# Is it possible to add a method to the prototype of the null value?

Tags: javascript, null, prototype

I think I know the answer to this question already, but I'm looking for confirmation.

What I would like to do is call toString() on a variable and if null return an empty string. I know I can convert null to "null" with String(null), but that seems so ugly if I want to do something like this:

```
var amount = myPossiblyNullVar.toString().toFloat();
```

or even more simply

```
var amount = myPossiblyNullVar.toFloat();
```

Where I have defined toFloat() as

```
String.prototype.toFloat = function() {
  var float;
  float = parseFloat(this.cleanNum());
  if (isNaN(float)) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return float;
  }
};
```

Based on what I have read, it seems that extending NULL in JavaScript is not possible. Can anyone confirm this or provide an alternative that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Yes; that is completely impossible.

Comment: How about guarding it with `var amount = maybeNull || maybeNull.toFloat();` instead? (if you do that for every occurrence of the variable consistently, then the `null` will silently propagate through without an error.)

Comment: TPC. That's a good suggestion. The way I'm handling it at the moment looks like `var amount = String(maybeNull).toFloat();` I'd just like something that looks like a chain of method calls. Dumb, but it bothers me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to modify the JavaScript null prototype.

```
var amount = maybeNull ? maybeNull.toFloat() : null;
```

If you have null propagation support (ES7)

```
 var amount = maybeNull?.toFloat();
```

If maybeNull is null, `?.` will return null instead of trying to call `toFloat()`.